# Avoid for loop to make more efficient this code

Tags: pandas, dataframe, performance, for-loop, multi-index

I have a big data frame and I need to apply a double if condition to each cell of it.
My code works but it is really slow. I would like to have a code that is more efficient.

di, dm and dmm are data frame with multi index column
dm is the rolling median of the data frame so it has the first 60 values = 0
dmm is a linear transformation of dm so it also has the first 60 values = 0
di, dm and dmm have all the same size, the same index and the same columns name
the data frame you see above is a copy of one similar taken from another question
my has 2520 rows x 4015 columns, the first level column index contains 803 columns each key so, the first level column index has 5 category, each category has 803 columns that in total are 4015.

I need to apply this formula for each cell of di:

```
 = dm + 5dmm if  >= dm + 5dmm or
 = dm - 5dmm if  <= dm - 5dmm
```

this is my code:

```
for i in range(len(di)):
    for j in range(len(di.columns)):
        if di.iloc[i,j] >= dm.iloc[i,j] + 5 * dmm.iloc[i,j]:
            di.iloc[i,j] = dm.iloc[i,j] + 5 * dmm.iloc[i,j]
        elif di.iloc[i,j] <= dm.iloc[i,j] - 5 * dmm.iloc[i,j]:
            di.iloc[i,j] = dm.iloc[i,j] - 5 * dmm.iloc[i,j]`
```

in this data frame the first level column index has two classes, each class contains 3 columns

```
                 JAN                 Feb            
                PRICE AMOUNT NAME   PRICE AMOUNT NAME
     2011-03-31     2      7    3       6      0    5
     2011-04-01     6      2    5       0      4    2
     2011-04-04     9      0    7       2      7    9
     2011-04-05     5      3    5       7      9    9
```

This is a simil-image of the data frame

[image]

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a bit hacky, but you can try with multiple [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)s. [I don't know any other flexible element-wise method for DataFrames...]

```py
def my_formula(di_dm_dmm_vals):
    di_val, dm_val, dmm_val = di_dm_dmm_vals
    if di_val >= dm_val + 5*dmm_val: return dm_val + 5*dmm_val
    if di_val <= dm_val - 5*dmm_val: return dm_val - 5*dmm_val
    return di_val ## [ no need for elif/else after return ]
```

```py
listify = lambda x: [x]
df_new = di.applymap(listify) + dm.applymap(listify) + dmm.applymap(listify) 
df_new = df_new.applymap(my_formula)
```

[Using `listify` then `+` creates a DataFrame of lists of which can each can be passed as a `di_dm_dmm_vals` argument to `my_formula`.]

<sub>**Please note that this will only work properly is all 3 DataFrames have the same shape.**</sub>

Comment: it says NameError: name 'di_dm_dmm' is not defined; it referres on the second row of the function

Comment: @AlessandroMarchi sorry about the typo - it should have been `di_dm_dmm_vals` (I've corrected it)

Comment: Thank you very much! it works and it is much much faster than before